# O que significa “súper”, “híper”, “mega”, “blaster”, “ultra”?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, significado-em-contexto

Há um tempo, usava-se esse palavreado em propagandas de eletrônicos em comerciais televisivos aqui no Brasil. Atualmente já nem vejo mais dizerem isso, nem outras variáveis que já nem me lembro mais quais eram.

O que queriam dizer, visto que o “súper” parece ser o mais inferior; o “híper”, o segundo mais inferior; e assim respectivamente? Seria uma forma de dizer que é o bom, o melhor, “o mais melhor”, “o mais melhor que o melhor”, etc., que é o topo de linha, ou mesmo não sendo o topo de linha, uma forma de atrair o público-alvo?

Comment: Sou brasileiro e nunca vi propaganda dizendo isso, talvez pela minha idade, mas é comuníssimo eu e com quem convivo dizermos isso aí. Sempre interpretei essas palavras como sinónimos para advérbio “muito”, tanto que é normal eu falar “isso é hiper legal”, por exemplo. Porém, “súper”, “híper”, “mega” e “ultra” são apenas sufixos, para o Priberam e Aulete... “Blaster” eu não encontrei em dicionários... Fico curioso para ler a futura resposta.

Comment: Quando eu era criança (últimas décadas do milênio passado) existia uma hierarquia entre estes prefixos: Super < Hiper < Ultra. Coroborando esta hipótese, existiam _mercados_ normalmente de bairro, menores. Existiam _supermercados_, maiores, com todo tipo de produtos. E por fim foram criados os _hipermercados_, supostamente, ainda maiores, com itens os mais variados, de comida a pneus automotivos, p.ex..

Comment: Já [Mega é um prefixo do sistema Internacional de Unidades, que indica um milhão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega). _Blaster_, para mim, como indicativo de tamanho é novidade, parece um pouco deslocado seu uso com relação aos outros termos da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Não chega a ser considerado propaganda enganosa, é apenas o uso de linguagem estrondosa, exagerada, [hiperbólica](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/hip%C3%A9rbole), com o objetivo mais de chamar a atenção que de enganar.

Essas palavras específicas são coloquiais, neologismos ou anglicismos. O prefixo "super-" [é um](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/super-?express=-super):

> elemento de formação de palavras que exprime a ideia de superioridade

e dele se deriva o "súper", que em parte já até está [dicionarizado](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/super):

> advérbio
> *coloquial* muito; bastante
> Do elemento de formação super-

Informalmente se pode fazer o mesmo com [hiper-](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/hiper-), [mega-](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/mega-), [*blaster*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blaster) (detonador, destruidor, etc.), [ultra-](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ultra-), etc.

Se seu uso tem diminuído, provavelmente se deve apenas a ter saído de moda, sendo substituído por outras formas de chamar atenção do consumidor, como se fez com a introdução da "*Black Friday*" no Brasil.

Comment: O OP nos apresenta duas perguntas: o significado das palavras/prefixos, e se elas são usadas como propaganda enganosa.  A primeira é fácil de responder e apresentar referências.  A resposta à segunda, no entanto, será sempre baseada em opinião. Concordo com a sua, mas não deixa de ser uma opinião.

Comment: @Centaurus, concordo. Devemos sugerir que o OP remova essa pergunta da postagem? (Daí eu removeria também minha resposta.)

Comment: Devido à qualidade da sua resposta, acho que é uma contribuição que deveria ser mantida.

Comment: @Centaurus e Stafusa, lembremo-nos que perguntas de opinião não são permitidas, tanto que é possível fechar uma pergunta exatamente por isso.

Comment: @Schilive, você poderia remover o `Seria isso propaganda enganosa na qual o povo já não cai mais?` da pergunta, ou sugerir que o OP o faça, se julgar que é o mais adequado.

Comment: Fiz a alteração sugerida no texto, mas tive que consertar a sugestão do título, que estava escrita "suúer" em lugar de "súper". Inclusive, gostaria de uma revisão de vocês, sobre a palavra "súper", pois, parece-me que ela não tem o acento agudo no "u", que foi sugerido, na grafia atual.

Comment: @renanlinux Também estranhei o acento, inclusive porque é possível encontrar dicionários em que ele não consta, contudo, paroxítonas terminadas em "r" [levam acento](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-paroxitonas/). Acho que farei uma pergunta a respeito.

Comment: Fiz a [pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8319/2764).

Answer (score 1):

Lembro que era bem comum essa frase há uns 7 ou 8 anos, adicionada de "master" no fim, e encontrei até uma tese de linguística sobre o tema, em relação do uso comum da expressão, muito mais do que seu uso como prefixos (https://repositorio.ufjf.br/jspui/handle/ufjf/7174), mas havia discordâncias de qual seria maior: mega ou hiper, ultra ou master e por aí vai.

Seguindo essa linha da tese, de Linguística Centrada no Uso, vale lembrar que logo depois veio o "uber" (https://oglobo.globo.com/rio/mega-blaster-uber-17051022) e fomos descobrindo novas grandezas na escala - como o tera, peta, exa etc. - enquanto a frase foi aparentemente caindo em desuso, mas ainda vejo com certa frequência nas redes como o Twitter.