# "Súper" ou "super" - a palavra leva acento ou não?

Tags: acentuação

A palavra coloquial "súper" claramente deveria ser acentuada [de acordo com a regra](https://www.normaculta.com.br/palavras-paroxitonas/):

> Apenas são acentuadas graficamente as palavras paroxítonas terminadas em **r**, l, n, x, ps, ã, ãs, ão, ãos, em um, uns, om, ons, us, i, is, ei, eis. [...]
> açúcar [...] flúor;

E é assim que ela é encontrada nos dicionários da [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/super) e da [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/super).

No entanto, a grafia sem o acento parece comum em pt-BR (e.g., "Ela é super confiável.", "Acho isso super estranho.") e também se encontra em dicionários menos estabelecidos, como o [dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/super/) e o [pt.TheFreeDictionary](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/super), além de fazer parte do nome da revista portuguesa [Super Interessante](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Interessante_(Portugal)).

Se poderia dizer que, ainda que apenas coloquialmente, a grafia sem o acento também é correta?

Comment: Mas qual seria o critério para grafia coloquialmente correta? Há muito pessoal que escreve coloquialmente sem acentos. Em *Super interessante*, a grafia correta seria *Superinteressante:* esse *Super* é o prefixo, não é nem o adjetivo nem o substantivo. O pessoal com nomes toma mais liberdades.

Comment: @Jacinto, é mesmo possível que a pergunta não seja bem colocada. O que eu gostaria de ter como resposta seria, por exemplo, algo na linha de "Sim, há exemplos o bastante e constar no dicio comprova que é aceitável." ou "Não, não há exceções conhecidas para essa(s) regra(s), seria preciso uma adoção em massa para justificar a primeira."

Comment: @Jacinto Não resisti e fui procurar exemplos - achei o suficiente para me convencer de que o dicio está certo em incluir o verbete sem acento.

Comment: @Jacinto, a Superinteressante é a revista brasileira. Como aqui o prefixo está ligado, não levaria acento em hipótese alguma. Já a revista que o autor menciona é a portuguesa Super Interessante, que por decisão de alguma pessoa, talvez para diferenciar da brasileira, optou por grafar com os elementos separados por espaço.

Comment: Depois de todos os bons comentários, resolvi que irei acrescentar um assento no meu primeiro nome!

Comment: @Ricárdo, no cartório e tudo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escreve Fernando Pestana em A Gramática para Concursos Públicos, p. 25:

"Não se acentuam afixos (prefixos ou falsos prefixos) paroxítonos terminados em **-r** ou -i, **exceto quando
substantivados: hiper- (o híper), mini- (a míni).**"

No dia a dia, podemos dizer algo como:

"Vamos ao (prep. A + artigo O) super?"
[entenda-se: super = supermercado]

Ora, como se vê, "super" vem substantivado.

Logo, segundo a regra: "Vamos ao súper?"

É estranho até para o corretor do site, que está indicando erro de ortografia. Mas fazer o quê? Quem programou o corretor desconhece as regras do escrever...

Comment: Muito bom! Bem-vindo, Arthur, excelente primeira contribuição. Seria ótimo também saber o porquê dessa exceção, mas está claro que a descrição do livro reflete o uso.

Comment: Imagino que a exceção para prefixos seja por que não são palavras completas e também por causa do hífen. Se não houvesse a exceção, poderíamos ter um supercarro súper-rápido (sem e com acento, respectivamente, só porque precisamos do hífen para separar r-r). Mas se prefixos forem usados como palavras independentes, não se encontra maneira de justificar a falta de acento e fizeram a regra dos "prefixos substantivados" (ou adjetivados, eu acrescentaria).

Answer (score 2):

Sim, a palavra sem acento é aceitável, ao menos coloquialmente - ou isso, ou a omissão do acento é um erro surpreendentemente difundido, mesmo entre profissionais da escrita.

Verifica-se que ela não apenas está [dicionarizada](https://www.dicio.com.br/super/), como aparece com frequência na imprensa desde pelo menos 2003, [BBC Brasil](https://www.bbc.com/portuguese/ciencia/story/2003/09/printable/030916_internetebc):

> mesmo com conexões **super rápidas**, ainda são necessárias horas

Outros exemplos da BBC são:

> - essa ideia de que era [super produtivo](https://www.bbc.com/portuguese/vert-cap-51014598).
> - mas agora é [super saudável](https://www.bbc.com/portuguese/geral-47361550)

E há exemplos também na Folha de São Paulo:

> - O mundo está [super incerto](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/mercado/2020/12/chefe-do-airbnb-o-mundo-esta-superinseguro.shtml)
> - Foi [super tranquilo](https://f5.folha.uol.com.br/musica/2020/12/luisa-sonza-anitta-e-pabllo-lancam-parceria-e-falam-em-usar-modo-turbo-contra-preconceito.shtml)
> - O rebu pegou [super mal](https://f5.folha.uol.com.br/colunistas/tonygoes/2020/12/que-a-morte-de-nicette-bruno-sirva-para-nos-conscientizarmos-do-perigo-da-covid-19.shtml)
> - Estou [super feliz](https://f5.folha.uol.com.br/televisao/2020/12/the-voice-brasil-de-virada-victor-alves-vence-reality-nao-tenho-palavras.shtml) de estar fazendo parte da história
> - uma discussão [super inovadora](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/esporte/2020/12/museu-do-futebol-faz-vaquinha-para-criar-audioguia-do-futebol-feminino.shtml)
> - é um país inovador e [super aberto](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/mercado/2020/12/parceria-com-a-suecia-em-startups-busca-pesquisadores-do-brasil.shtml)

Assim como no Jornal de Notícias (JN), de Portugal:

> - Se hoje sou um homem [super feliz](https://www.jn.pt/pessoas/in/fabio-coentrao-declara-se-a-mulher-se-hoje-sou-um-homem-super-feliz-devo-o-a-ela-9265500.html) devo-o a ela
> - os adversários "foram [super fortes](https://www.jn.pt/desporto/joao-almeida-os-outros-eram-mais-fortes-e-nao-havia-nada-que-eu-pudesse-fazer-12951680.html)"
> - [Super estreitos](https://www.jn.pt/nacional/especial/arranha-ceus-lapis-estao-a-mudar-nova-iorque-11346807.html), super luxuosos e super caros. São assim os novos edifícios

Comment: Stafusa, mas “super” é paroxítona? Será que não é uma palavra átona?

Comment: @Schilive Na minha pronúncia é certamente /'super/. Acho que não tenho palavras átonas - [diz-se](https://gramaticaonline.com.br/lingua_no_dia_dia/tonicidade/) que "quando" e "porque" seriam átonos, mas eu falo com alguma ênfase a 1a e a última sílaba delas, respectivamente.

Comment: Stafusa, mas seria isso por serem as primeiras sílabas faladas? Tenta falar “super legal” e “súper legal”, então, vê se há diferença para ti — para mim, não há —. Como o sufixo “-super” é átono, não tem acento — novamente, tenta falar “super-homem” e “súper-homem” —, talvez por isso o escrevam assim, mas é só uma hipótese.

Comment: @Schilive Sim, também pronuncio “super legal” = “súper legal”, e em "super-homem" o "su" me parece subtônico (talvez por influência do inglês _superman_?) e o "ho" tônico. E, se concordamos que "super" é paroxítona, então a grafia sem acento, "super", é ou exceção à regra, ou incorreta. Como com facilidade achei diversos exemplos em sites de notícias de "super" (e essa grafia ainda me parece mais natural, por alguma razão), ainda mantenho minha resposta - mas continuo aberto a uma contraditória, claro.

Comment: Acho que colocastes muito bem: é um erro surpreendentemente difundido.

Answer (score 2):

Súper acentuado é a interjeição, que não vem acompanhada, só exprime satisfação. Súper!
Nos outros casos, inclusive os que você citou em sua autorresposta, super é prefixo de algum substantivo ou adjetivo e não leva acento.
Essa é a resposta para a pergunta principal. Agora vamos às deliberações que surgiram.

Super e supra vêm do latim e geraram um equivalente em português que é a preposição sobre. Como prefixos, super, supra, sobre, hiper, ultra, entre outros, devem estar ligados a algum outro elemento, ou separados por hífen.

Ainda valendo dos exemplos que você trouxe, você comentou que há um erro surpreendentemente difundido, e de fato há, mas não é a omissão do acento e sim a separação do prefixo.
Idealmente, segundo o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990, todos eles deveriam estar juntos: superprodutivo, supersaudável, superincerto, supertranquilo, supermal, superfeliz, superinovadora, superaberto, superfortes, superestreitos.
A única outra possibilidade seria separá-los com hífen, mas isso apenas nos casos onde o segundo elemento começa com h ou r. Você não citou nenhum, mas temos super-homem, super-rápido, como exemplos.

Comment: +1 Perspectiva interessante. Mas penso que o uso como advérbio, ao invés de prefixo, parece estar se estabelecendo e a distinção é clara: dizer que alguém é um "superamigo" remeteria mais aos "superamigos" do desenho/gibi... muito melhor separado ("Ele é super meu amigo."; também: "Essa ideia é super boa."). Penso que o prefixo serve-se melhor para criar um novo conceito: "superresfriado", por exemplo, é um [termo técnico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrefus%C3%A3o) que não tem necessariamente a ver com temperaturas ultrabaixas; "superbug" também tem um significado específico (resistência).

Comment: Dizer que de tal modo é muito melhor é somente uma opinião. Eu respeito, mas não temos como afirmar ou mensurar. Esse uso é muito mais frequente no português falado, concorda? Eu, particularmente, não perceberia diferença se alguém me dissesse "ele é meu superamigo" ou "ele é meu 'super amigo'". E em nenhuma das hipóteses ia passar pela minha cabeça que o cidadão em questão detém superpoderes; ou que alguém que diz estar super-resfriado pegou uma variante específica da doença (a menos que dissesse "peguei o super-resfriado", grifo no artigo).

Answer (score 0):

O professor da especialização em Linguística e Acordo Ortográfico disse que súper enquanto adjetivo, ele é acentuado, por exemplo: Tu és súper! Uma vez que a regra das paroxítonas terminadas em R exige o acento.

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, você poderia incluir a qual professor você se refere e/ou usar outras referências?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A resposta para sua dúvida é que nao há um consenso unânime entre os gramáticos da língua portuguesa no tocante a SUPER e SÚPER, entre outras regras de acentuação, como por exemplo o uso facultativo da vírgula.

Os dicionários por si só já deixam explícito a divergência doutrinária.

Comment: portuglish, seja muito bem-vindo ao site! E obrigado pela contribuição! Porém, uma dúvida: por que os gramáticos se concerniriam com a ortografia?

Comment: Você poderia citar alguma fonte ou ao menos apontar um dicionário mais estabelecido que os que encontrei ([dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/super/) e [pt.TheFreeDictionary](https://pt.thefreedictionary.com/super))?

Comment: @Schilive A divergência doutrinária do qual me refiro é minoritária e o motivo é justamente pelas dúvidas abordada nos comentários aqui. Eu particulamente prefiriria que todas as formas de usa da palavra super ficassem sem acento mesmo.

Comment: @stafusa A divergência é minoritária e é justamente por causa dos dicionários mencionados aqui, pois seus escritores são gramáticos especialistas da língua portuguesa. Mas respeito o ponto de vista de ambos. Não pesquisei a fundo mais dicionários além destes.